# What is the difference between object and entity in the database?

Tags: database, object, entity

What is the difference between object and entity in the database?
Please explain with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An entity is an abstract concept that's typically represented by a table in a database schema. The term object usually refers to in-memory data structures. An object that represents an entity may be called an entity object (often mapped to a row in a database table), that is it's an instance of an entity class (often mapped to a table).

A database object is represented as database, schema, table, column, primary key, and foreign key While a database Entity is a concept or object of importance about which data must be captured.